# Prove $x^i \mod (x^4 + 1) = x^{i \mod 4}$ in $GF(2)[x]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

These are my notes so far:

1. $\frac{x^{i}}{x^4 + 1}$ yields two polynoms $q(x)$ and $r(x)$, s.t.  $q(x)(x^4 + 1) + r(x)$
2. $(x^4 + 1)|(x^{i} - r(x))$ (from 1)
3. We should prove that $r(x)$ = $x^{i \mod 4}$ (Induction hypothesis?)
4. We have it that $(x^4 + 1)|(x^i - x^{i \mod 4})$ (from 2. and 3.)
5. There must be a $q(x)$, s.t. $x^i - x^{i \mod 4} = q(x)(x^4 + 1)$ (divisibility property, from 2)

So now my approach was to perform the induction as follows.

Base case $i=0$:

- $x^0 - x^{0 \mod 4} = q(x)(x^4 + 1)$
- $x^0 - x^0 = q(x)(x^4 + 1)$
- $0 = q(x)(x^4 + 1) \Rightarrow q(x) = 0$

But from here on I'm stuck. Is my approach right? If so, how can I perform the inductive step? What am I missing?

---

**Edit**: Proof attempt based on the [hint from Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738675/93310)

- *Lemma 1*. Every integer $n >= 0$ can be written in the form $n = r+4q$, with $0 \leq r < 4$ and $q \geq 0$.
- *Lemma 2*. In $GF(2)[x]$, $x^{r+4q} \Rightarrow x^r$ (See hint in the answer)
- If we put $i$ in the form $r+4q$:
  $x^{r+4q} \mod (x^4 + 1) = x^{r+4q \mod 4} \Rightarrow
   x^r \mod (x^4 + 1) = x^r$

  From Lemma 2 it follows, that r must be $0 \leq r < 4$.
  Since all $x^r$ with $r \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ cannot be expressed as quotient of $x^4 + 1$ and $deg(x^r) < deg(x^4 + 1)$, $x^r$ is the remainder.

Comment: It might be easier to prove that if it is true for $i$ then it is true for $i+4$. Then you only need to prove it for $i=0,1,2,3.$

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$, $x^4+1=(x+1)^4$. Not sure how much that helps, but it seems relevant. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ 2\equiv0\equiv x^4\! + 1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{x^4}\equiv -1\equiv \color{#c00}1\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large r+4q} = x^{\large r} (\color{#c00}{x^{\large 4}})^{\large q}\equiv x^{\large r}\color{#c00}{(1)}^{\large q}\equiv x^{\large r}$

Comment: Thank you! I edited my post and added a proof attempt based on your hint. Is this proof now sound?

Comment: @moeso If you proceed as above you don't need induction (it is encapsulated in the invocation of the division algortihm to write $n = 4q + r,\ 0\le r < 4,\,$ i.e. $\,r = n\ {\rm mod}\ 4).\,$ If you must explicitly use induction then, as follows, you can directly inline into your proof the division algorithm result: $\, x^4\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,x^{n+4}\equiv x^n \equiv x^{n\ {\rm mod}\ 4} $ by complete induction. But $\ n\ {\rm mod}\ 4\equiv (n\!+\!4)\ {\rm mod}\ 4,\,$ which yields the inductive step.

Comment: No, I don't need to explicitly use induction. So I removed it. Thanks again!